# How to reduce text size when it goes to second line?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, textview

Say i have `textview` size is `18sp`, if `textview` goes to second line, how to reduce `textview` size?
any idea?

```
TextView text= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
text.setTextSize(18);
//how to reduce text size if text goes to second line when it's too large?
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is it `TextView` size or the **textSize** inside it. Since `sp` is used for textsize and `dp` is used for view's size.

Comment: If you want to reduce the text size than you might add text watcher and in that onTextChanged method you can check if line count is greter than one with textView.getLineCount() and can change the text size.

Comment: @KunalK will you please explain in brief.

Comment: Please Go through my answer it will Surly works..!!

Comment: @user1632209 thanks but i don't want to use library.

Comment: It is not library it is just one call have to add in your project.
That`s all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind [TextWatcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html) to you textView as done in following code snippet and listen for text changes in your textView.

```
...
txtView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt);
txtView.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if(txtView.getLineCount() > 1){
                txtView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 14);
            }
        }
});
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Use spannable as

```
String s= "Hello Everyone next line";
 SpannableString ss1=  new SpannableString(s);
 ss1.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(2f), 0,13, 0); // set size of Hello Everyone
 ss1.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(f), 14,23, 0);// set size of Next line
 TextView tv= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview);
 tv.setText(ss1);
```